# Out of memory error while using for loop in a matlab code

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

I have a 1x46 cell of different length cells.

I want to zero pad each cell to maximum length cell because I want to apply cell2mat function and in order to apply that I need to make this cell consistent.

But whenever I run my code it gives memory error.

The maximum length is 6691240 i.e there are 6691240 elements in the maximum length cell

The code is as follows

```
for i=1:numel(X1)
  if size(X1{i}) < 6691240
  X1{i}(end,6691240)=0;
  end
end
```

Comment: 8*46*6691240 = 2GB, so this should work if you have at least 8GB for further operations on the data. But you have `X1{I}(end, 6.7M)` -> if your `X1` had say 10k elements it will now become a matrix with 10k * 6.7M elements and this will be obviously far too large.

Comment: yes i know that can u suggest some possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand is that each cell is a vector, and the length of each such vector needs to be 6691240. Thus, the code needs to be changed as:

```
for i=1:length(X1)
    if length(X1{i}) < 6691240
        X1{i}(6691240)=0;
    end
end
```